# DiscordJS v14 Increasing Counter by Sent Embeds

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying for every message is being sent to increase the counter by one (+1). I am trying to make it but I got confused, could you please help me out?
Example: Review #1, Review #2 etc..

```
    client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.channel.id == `ChannelID`) {
    //Reviews Channel ID
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let today = new Date();
    let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = `${dd}/${mm}/${yyyy}`;
    count++
    message.delete();
    const reviews = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setAuthor({
        name: `${message.member.user.tag}`,
        iconURL: `${message.member.displayAvatarURL({
          dynamic: true,
          size: 4096,
          text: "Review #" + count,
        })}`,
      })
      .setDescription(`**${message.content}**`)
      .setColor(botConfig.EmbedColor)
      .setFooter({
        text: `${botConfig.Text} | ${today}`,
      });
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [reviews] });
  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you have the `count` variable declared?

Comment: @Leonerrr_ above the `message.delete();` and inside in the `.setAuthor`

Comment: He is asking where/how did you declare the variable. You are updating it above `messege.delete()` and using it inside `.setAuthor`. 
Also, what is it showing? Review #0? Is it showing any error?